# Some multitouch locations are not being detected in wp7 silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna, multi-touch, windows-phone-7.1

Hi I am trying to create a simple drum machine application in silverlight for wp7.  I am finding that about 60% of the time when I tap the screen in 2 different locations at the same time (or almost the same time) one of the locations is not being detected.

I have wired up the Layoutroot grid to raise events on manipualtion started as shown below.  The problem is about 60% of the time when I press both the section of the screen assigned to the high hat and the section of the screen assigned to the kick drum or the snare at the same time only the touch location for one of these sounds will be captured in the touchpanel.

I am testing on a LG optimus running mango. Any ideas on how to get around this issue? Would polling instead of raising events yield better results? Am I better of creating this application as an XNA game rather than a silverlight application?  Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" ManipulationStarted="LayoutRoot_ManipulationStarted">
```

Comment: It turns out polling instead of raising events fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a listbox item and a context menu.
I fixed it like this:

Attach your rootframte to  MouseLeftButtonDown="LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonDown"

This event is 100%  always raised.

In the event Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(null);

now it is time to identify the object, if any, that is located at those screencoordinates.

Below is my code to identify a listboxitem. You can use it with your own UI objects:

```
        ListBoxItem listBoxItem = null;
        List<UIElement> listControls = (List<UIElement>)VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(clickPoint , this);
        foreach (UIElement ctrl in listControls)
        {
            if (ctrl is ListBoxItem)
            {
                listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)ctrl;
                break;
            }
        }
        //get the index of the selected listboxitem.
        ListBox view = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(listBoxItem) as ListBox;
```

Cheers, 
Vlad